# cufon.js custom text gradiant

Tags: javascript, css, cufon

My CSS Gradients:

h1:

```
linear-gradient(left, #ffffff 0%, #ffffff 50%, #fafafa 75%, #e3e3e3 100%)
```

h2:

```
linear-gradient(45deg, #dbdbdb 0%, #dbdbdb 25%, #ffffff 60%, #ffffff 100%)
```

h3:

```
linear-gradient(45deg, #e3e3e3 0%, #ffffff 45%, #ffffff 100%)
```

I need to apply **the same** CSS gradients to cufon.js instead of the below gradient.

```
Cufon.replace('h1', {
    color: '-linear-gradient(white, black)'
});

Cufon.replace('h2', {
    color: '-linear-gradient(white, black)'
});

Cufon.replace('h3', {
    color: '-linear-gradient(white, black)'
});
```

Unfortunately, Cufon colors goes from top to bottom as the below demo, any solutions?

http://jsfiddle.net/yrfYX/17/